# Capture image of parent view in iOS 5

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-graphics, ios5

I use the code below to capture an image of the parent view to use as a background in a modal view.  It no longer works in iOS 5 (the variable "parentViewImage" below is null.  Can someone help?

```
// grab an image of our parent view
UIView *parentView = self.parentViewController.view;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(parentView.bounds.size);
[parentView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *parentViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: +1 I had the same problem. I moved your answer out of the question and in to an answer. You should accept it to let people know that it's correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iOS 5 you need to use `presentingViewController` instead of `parentViewController` property.

```
UIView *parentView = self.presentingViewController.view;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(parentView.bounds.size);
[parentView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *parentViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```